# Search Bar not showing on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uisearchbar

I'm pulling my hair out with this one. I've created this view in storyboard:

[image]

When I'm running on an iPhone 5S it's working fine, the Search Bar is displayed like it should. But when I'm running on an iPhone 4S the Search Bar isn't displayed as you can see in the image below:
[image]

Running on emulator shows the Search Bar correctly in either sizes. In my `viewDidLoad` I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.processTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.processTableView setDataSource:self];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

I just found out that my issue is related to the line `self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;` but I don't understand why. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: did u try scrolling it down? the scrollbar could get behind the nav bar.

Comment: Hi Mr.T, yes, I've scrolled to see if it's behind but nothing. I also tried to add it out the TableView but with the line ´self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;´ it isn't displayed.

Comment: try this, select your `tableview`, then `clear constraints` .then select 
`Reset to Suggested Constraints`.(select these from `Resolve Auto Layout issues`)

Comment: Also, can someone explain what I've done wrong to get down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used part of the code provided by @user1079052:

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

Adding it to my existent code made the Search Bar visible on iPhone 4S and maintained the same behavior on iPhone 5S. However, the Search Bar were displayed OVER the Table View. To solve this I calculated the bar height and set it again. So, my `viewDidLoad` looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.processTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.processTableView setDataSource:self];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    CGFloat height = [self.searchController.searchBar systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    CGRect frame = self.searchController.searchBar.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = frame;
    self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

I would like to thanks all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

This is how I implement it:

```
  self.searchController =
      [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
  self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
  self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

  self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
  self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
  [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
  self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

Comment: Hi, I've defined the `definesPresentationContext` but your answer helped me to test some other situations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the search bar of your searchController to the headerView instead of setting the HeaderView to the searchBar. Something like:

```
[self.processTableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
```

If you do this, that means to can remove the searchBar from your storyboard.

Comment: Hi Charles, I've removed the Search Bar from Storyboard and added the suggested line but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the bar in behind when scroll down, should be a constraints the problem. Catch a try with deleting manualy constraints (not "clear constraints").

Comment: Achron, for `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` there are no constraints available to create. Search Bar is automatically added to the top of the Table View.

Comment: The problem is no Search Bar's constraints, but can be the view's. I see you have them in the View and Content View. I immagine you created the views for 5S for instance, but the same constraints remain also for the 4S. Maybe, them should be a problem.